# Logstash Grok Regex: get each line in each block

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

I need a custom [logstash-grok](/questions/tagged/logstash-grok) regex pattern

Some sample data:

```
    abc blabla
    [BLOCK]
    START=1
    END=2
    [/BLOCK]
    more blabla
    [BLOCK]
    START=3
    END=4
    [/BLOCK]
```

Note: each line ends in a newline character.

How do I capture all START and END values?
The desired result is:

```
{ "BLOCK1": { "START:"1", "END":"2"} }, "BLOCK2": { "START":"3", "END":"4" } }
```

I tried

```
START \bSTART=(?<start>\d*)
END \bEND=(?<end>\d*)
```

but the result is the values of *only the first* block:
`{ "start": "1", "end": "2" }`

I also tried using the multiline character `(?m)` in front of the grok pattern but that doesn't work either...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check [this page](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/grok-field-extract-one-pattern-multiple-matches/130497). You will need `r = s.scan(/\[BLOCK\]\R(?:.*\R)*?\[\/BLOCK\]/)`

Comment: Or, `s.scan(/\[BLOCK\]\n(?:.*\n)*?\[\/BLOCK\]/).map{ |x| [x[/START=(\d+)/,1], x[/END=(\d+)/,1]]}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your help! I don't get the desired result though. The grok pattern is `%{START:start}` and the custom pattern is now your suggestion: `START s.scan(...).map{...}`, but I get `{"start": "x"}` as a result. Would you be so kind to enlighten me more?
Note: I use this [site](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) as testbed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew PS: I replaced `s.scan(...` with `event.get('message').scan(...`, but this also results in an empty "x". In short, I don't know how to address the input in the custom pattern using the site aforementioned...